# why custom element extended from the div doesn't function like div in terms of styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am creating a custom html element  by extending the div like this

```
class CustomDiv extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
    super();
    }
}

customElements.define('custom-div', CustomDiv, { extends: 'div' });
```

and i use that in html

```
<custom-div>

  <ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  </ul>

</custom-div>
```

when i try to apply styling to this custom-div using css

```
custom-div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

but it doesnt work, whats wrong with my code? here is the [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ay7x3pL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right!

You don´t see background because `custom-div` doesn´t have display property. Please add `display : block` in your code

```js
class CustomDiv extends HTMLElement {
 constructor() {
   super();
 }
}

customElements.define('custom-div', CustomDiv, { extends: 'div' });
```

```css
custom-div {
  background-color: tomato;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#custom-elements -->
<custom-div>
  
  <ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  </ul>
  
</custom-div>
```

Comment: I am curious to know why it didnt extend the styling from div element.